# After change in URLBLockList registrykey for Edge, I need to restart Edge to reflect the changes

Tags: python, java, browser, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have a use-case where what currently user is working on windows machine, we need to blocklist few websites.

I am able to do this but where I am stuck is that we need to restart Edge every time the registry value changes otherwise changes are not reflected. I am assuming that edge is caching the allowlist/blocklist when it start. Any way I can disable this

Registry key path - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\URLBlocklist

Answer (score 1):

Even though [it is stated as "Dynamic Policy Refresh: Yes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#urlblocklist), it only works when you configure the policy via group policy editor instead of registry settings. It is a [limitation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767860) acknowledged by Chromium Team.

You can try "Reg Key observer" mentioned there by the Chromium Team, but an easier way for you to do this is to download the Edge group policy template, and then configure the policy via group policy editor. It supports dynamic policy refresh. You can check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/configure-microsoft-edge#1-download-and-install-the-microsoft-edge-administrative-template) if you are interested.